# Get DOM Element from React.createElement()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, twilio

Is there a way to get basic DOM Element from React.createElement?

Like I'm trying to create a list of React audio elements for each participant in the conversation and I need to attach a track to an element, but it's not working with react elements...

My idea is something like this, but this is not working

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>()
const addAudioTrack = (track: AudioTrack) => {
    const audio = React.createElement("audio", {key: track.name, ref: ref})
    console.log(ref.current)
    track.attach(ref.current)
    setAudioTracks((prevTracks: any) => [...prevTracks, audio])
}
```

**EDIT**: reproducible example can't be totally provided because for "track" you need Twilio but here is something that you can try... I just want to know if there is a possibility to get react DOM element from ReactElement or  I need to use another approach

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from "react";

const NewTest = () => {

    const [audioTracks, setAudioTracks] = useState<any>([])

    const ref = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>()
    const addAudioTrack = (track: any) => {
        const audio = React.createElement("audio", {key: track.name, ref: ref})
        console.log(ref.current)
        if(ref.current) console.log("it is working")
        // track.attach(ref.current)
        setAudioTracks((prevTracks: any) => [...prevTracks, audio])
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {
                addAudioTrack({name: `audioTrack-${(((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1)}`})
            }}>
                AddTrack
            </button>
            {audioTracks && audioTracks.map((audio: any) => {
                return <div key={audio.key} style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "red"}}>{audio} {audio.key}</div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewTest
```

Comment: Please share reproducible example

Comment: Please post the component in which this function is being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you might be thinking of this the wrong way. You do need a `ref` to use `track.attach`, but you can still handle the creation of elements via JSX.

I'd create an `<AudioTrack>` element that you can render with each audio track that uses `useRef` and `useEffect` to get an `<audio>` element and use `track.attach`. Something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const AudioTrack = ({ audioTrack }) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    audioTrack.attach(ref.current);
    return () => {
      audioTrack.detach();
    }
  }, [audioTrack])
  
  return <div><audio ref={ref}></div>;
}

export AudioTrack;
```

Then, in the parent container, you can render an `<AudioTrack>` for each of the `audioTracks` in your state.

I walk through how I created a [Twilio Video app using React Hooks in this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/video-chat-react-hooks), that might be helpful too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did in the end come up with two solutions. 
The first was something similar like you posted here.
The second was to use pure javascript **Audio** and **MediaStream**.
But I'm still curious if it is possible to do something like that in react for the future.

Comment: So, I think the point is that you don't get access to a direct DOM element in React because it messes with React's rendering. The way you should access DOM elements is with refs, and even then it's important to be mindful of the rendering process.